# Terraform input variables best solution?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am trying to create some resources with some defined variables that will be used.

I defined the variables with their own values

```
ingest_parameters = {
    x1  = {  
      ENV_GROUPID  = "xxxx"
      ENV_TOPIC    = "xxxx"
      ENV_USERNAME = "xxxx"
    }
    x2 = {
      ENV_GROUPID   = "yyyy"
      ENV_TOPIC     = "yyyy"
      ENV_USERNAME  = "yyy"
    }
    x3 = {
     ENV_GROUPID    = "zzzz"
     ENV_TOPIC      = "zzzz"
     ENV_USERNAME   = "zzzz"
    }
    x4 = {
     ENV_GROUPID  = "wwww"
     ENV_TOPIC    = "wwww"
     ENV_USERNAME = "wwww"  
    }
}
```

I created a for_each to get the above variables values into this module:

```
module "ingest_other" {

  for_each                                   = var.ingest_parameters
  source                                     = "./ingest_rest"
  tenant                                     = each.key
  ingest_ENV_GROUPID                         = each.value.ENV_GROUPID
  ingest_ENV_TOPIC                           = each.value.ENV_TOPIC
  ingest_ENV_USERNAME                        = each.value.ENV_USERNAME
  ingest_ENV_PASSWORD                        = ENV_PASSWORD  <-how to?

}
```

the data above data is then used here:

```
environment_variables = format("[ %s ]", join(", ", tolist([
  jsonencode(tomap({
    name  = "GROUPID"
    value = "var.ingest_ENV_GROUPID"
  })),
  jsonencode(tomap({
    name  = "TOPIC"
    value = "var.ingest_ENV_TOPIC"
  })),
  jsonencode(tomap({
    name  = "USERNAME"
    value = "var.ingest_ENV_USERNAME"
  })),
  jsonencode(tomap({
    name  = "PASSWORD"
    value = "var.ingest_ENV_PASSWORD"
  }))
])))
```

How can I put the ENV_PASSWORD for each of the 4 resources. I do not want to hard code them in the ingest_parameters.
Is there is a way that it when i do the plan it asks me for this 4 psswd variables?
any recommendation?

thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly recommend you utilize some secrets manager like Hashicorp Vault and not enter passwords manually in cli. Provided you create a secret with KV engine and path `ingest/secrets` and add values for each ENV_TOPIC (choose right parameter here, not sure if ENV_TOPIC is correct id...), you can do:

```
provider "vault" {
  address = "https://${var.vault_fqdn}"
}

data "vault_generic_secret" "secrets" {
  path = "ingest/secrets"  # <= just an example
}
```

And then:

```
module "ingest_other" {

  for_each                                   = var.ingest_parameters
  source                                     = "./ingest_rest"
  tenant                                     = each.key
  ingest_ENV_GROUPID                         = each.value.ENV_GROUPID
  ingest_ENV_TOPIC                           = each.value.ENV_TOPIC
  ingest_ENV_USERNAME                        = each.value.ENV_USERNAME
  ingest_ENV_PASSWORD                        = data.vault_generic_secret.secrets.data[each.value.ENV_TOPIC]

}
```

Also, you can just use tfvars file, which is still more handy and secure solution (if you remember to add `secrets.tfvars` to your `.gitignore`). Not sure which terraform version you are using, but if it is > 0.14 then you can use sensitive variables, as described [here](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/sensitive-variables). For example you could do:

variables.tf:

```
variable "secrets" {
  type = "map"
  default = {}
  sensitive = true
}
```

secrets.tfvars:

```
secrets = {
  "zzzz" : "zzzz-secret"
  "yyyy" : "yyyy-secret"
  "xxxx" : "xxxx-secret"
}
```

and then:

```
module "ingest_other" {

  for_each                                   = var.ingest_parameters
  source                                     = "./ingest_rest"
  tenant                                     = each.key
  ingest_ENV_GROUPID                         = each.value.ENV_GROUPID
  ingest_ENV_TOPIC                           = each.value.ENV_TOPIC
  ingest_ENV_USERNAME                        = each.value.ENV_USERNAME
  ingest_ENV_PASSWORD                        = var.secrets[each.value.ENV_TOPIC] # <= choose right parameter here, not sure if ENV_TOPIC is correct id...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there is a way that it when i do the plan it asks me for this 4
> psswd variables?

If you want it to ask you for each one, and you are going to type them in one at a time, then you simply need to define them as four separate variables without default values. It will then ask you to type each password before the `terraform plan` proceeds.